# How to use LCD Screen and IR Remote to broadcast a countdown

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, ir, remote-control

I am trying to use an IR Remote to input date's and time's for a countdown, so then the LCD will display a countdown, like this:

```
LCD: Enter Year
Remote-Input: 2021
LCD: Enter Month
Remote-Input: 08
LCD: Enter Day
Remote-Input: 20
LCD: Enter Hour
Remote-Input: 08
LCD: Enter Minute
Remote-Input: 00
LCD: Enter Second:
Remote-Input: 00
LCD: You have __ Years, __ Months, __ Days, __ Hours, __ Minutes, __ Seconds.
```

How do I do this?

Comment: GLHF! (You forgot to ask a question). However, my advice would be to do one thing at a time before connecting them all together.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I know how to ask a question. I was just in a rush.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question, @timemage

Comment: No problem.  As is, the question is more of a "how do I do my project" type question, which isn't what the site is meant for.  Presumably you've made an attempt at this and ran into at least one specific problem, ideally an Arduino specific problem.  If so, you can edit your question to make it about that one thing, and then the answer might be of use to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I do this?

I have no clue how you do that but I do know I would do that.

> I know how to ask a question.

Apparently not, your question is far from perfect (and my answer above is technically the only correct answer to that specific question). It doesn't tell us what you've tried, it doesn't tell us what you haven't tried. It not specific nor practical. Doesn't state your experience with Arduino, doesn't state which hardware you (would) be using. (Though I must say your example output thing is quite nice)

> I was just in a rush.

Isn't everyone nowadays? And why would we invest time in an answer on a question which has no effort put into it?

---

You're basically asking "How to do an Arduino project" (or any project), there's many ways but let's dive into it.

**0. Split up your project into smaller projects.**

Since it sounds as if you have no clue on how to get started or if you feel this project is daunting, it may help to make the 'problem' easier to get started. You can always add more complexity.

Make one Arduino program, which shows "Hello World" on the LCD.

Make one Arduino program, which receives IR codes and depending on which button pressed, shows "Hello" or "World" in your terminal.

**1. Research**

Search the internet, maybe there's projects like this. Try to google for "Arduino Countdown Timer". Check what design choices they made, what hardware they use and how they work in general.

**2. Design**

Make a design, not only about the aesthetic part, but also functionally. What happens if the timer depletes? Should it also have a buzzer? Does it need an enclosure?

And technically, how will it be powered?

**3. Acquire hardware**

As a starter; it can help to buy hardware from stores that also include example code.
Use the example code to test and verify your hardware and connections.

**4. Software**

If you're asking "How to write software", you're better off starting out with some example projects/tutorials which include the code and explain it.

But basically you should use the example code to drive the hardware, use examples on the internet combined with your own experience to create a program that matches your required behavior.

---

**If, along this path, you have a practical question. We will be much more able to, and happy to, help.**

Comment: I apologize for not meeting your criteria. I was just trying to get some help before my class started, hopefully someone like you would come across and help me. I appreciate your tips. I will follow these and then come back to re-ask the question if necessary. Thanks again!

Comment: I found this website, which seemed to help:

https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/hugonator/simple-lcd-timer-with-arduino-uno-ff3376

Comment: I like the buzzer idea. Would I use the active buzzer or passive buzzer? I don't know the difference.

Comment: An active buzzer will generate a tone by itself, so for simplicity use an active one. If you'd like to adjust the tone by yourself, you need a passive one.

Comment: Thanks! I have both :)

Comment: So I found a create.arduino.cc project that I had thought it was a countdown, but when I create it and upload it to my board, I found out that it's a timer. Like a kitchen timer. :I

Comment: A countdown is only different by doing -1 second instead of +1 second. And that you start at the maximum value instead of 0

Comment: Nice! thank you